Question about the use of Green's theorem in Do Carmo's proof of the local Gauss-Bonnet theorem.
This is Do Carmo's statement and proof of the local Gauss-Bonnet theorem in "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces":




My question is: how can he assert that
$$\sum_{i=0}^k \int_{s_i}^{s_{i+1}} \left(\frac{G_u}{2\sqrt{EG}} \frac{dv}{ds} - \frac{E_v}{2\sqrt{EG}} \frac{du}{ds}\right)\, ds = \iint_{\mathbf{x}^{-1} (R)} \left(\left(\frac{E_v}{2\sqrt{EG}}\right)_v + \left(\frac{G_u}{2\sqrt{EG}}\right)_u\right)\, du\, dv$$
using Green's theorem? As far as I can tell, the left hand integral is a line integral over $\alpha (I)$, which we turn into a regular integral over $I$. In other words, we are integrating over $\alpha (I) = \partial R$, meaning the double integral on the right hand side should be over $R$. Now $\mathbf{x}^{-1} (R)$ is clearly not $R$, so the step I'm missing is how we identify $\partial \mathbf{x}^{-1} (R) = \alpha (I)$.
Since $\mathbf{x}$ is a parametrisation, it is a homeomorphism, using which I have been able to get to $\partial \mathbf{x}^{-1} (R) = \mathbf{x}^{-1} (\partial R) = (\mathbf{x}^{-1} \circ \alpha) (I)$, but that still isn't $\alpha (I)$.
Help would be appreciated.

Because the line integral is in $uv$-space, it is in fact over $\mathbf x^{-1}(\alpha(I))$. The whole application of Green’s Theorem is in $U$.

@TedShifrin But then why can we turn it into a regular integral over $I$? From what I remember about line integrals, the line integral would have to be over $\alpha(I)$ for us to be able to do so.

Not at all. $(u(s),v(s))$ is the parametrization of $\mathbf x^{-1}\circ\alpha$. None of the integration occurs literally on $S$. (We indeed apply Green's Theorem, as I already said, entirely in $U$, in the $uv$-plane.)

@TedShifrin Alright, that makes sense. And we integrate piecewise because $\alpha$ is only piecewise regular (and so the piecewise integration "takes into account the corners"), correct?

Yes, together with the $\theta_i$’s.
